# Array store in array with multiple form

Tags: ajax, laravel, database, multidimensional-array, store

I am making a copy of form on click button , i want to store that all form data in database for a single input data is properly inserting , but for checked values how to store? This is how my form looks like[image: This Form copy i am making]

I am saving form data using loop , all data inserting properly as it is storing in sequence only , but how to save if in first from 2 box checked then it should store in first row of database , likewise second

This is my controller code

```
$customInputName = $request->input('customInputName');
        $inputType = $request->input('inputType');
        $checkedValues = $request->input('checkedValues');

        $customInputNameArray = json_decode($customInputName);
        $inputTypeArray = json_decode($inputType);
        $checkedValuesArray = json_decode($checkedValues);
        dd($checkedValuesArray);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($customInputNameArray); $i++) {
            $customInput = new inputForm();
            $customInput->customInputName = $customInputNameArray[$i];
            $customInput->inputType = $inputTypeArray[$i];
            // $customInput->validation = $checkedValuesArray[$i];
            $customInput->eventid = $eventId;
            $customInput->save();
        }
```

Checked values i am getting in all in one array of all forms , how can i make different array for both forms

Comment: I assume your validation field has something like `name="validations[]"` and as you can tell you can't say what values are from the first field and what are for the second field unless you maybe check for the order of the values. Instead you should scope all your field to the record being submitted, like `name="field[id or some index][validations][]"`

Comment: how can i pass @krisgjika ? As i am making copy of form so all inputs name will be same

Answer (score 0):

Try storing values in array if you are using just HTML input and text or object in case of JavaScript at front end. Instead of getting separately at backend.

For example:

```
Inputs[]['customInputName']
Inputs[]['inputType']
Inputs[]['checkedValues'] // if check store by name e.g., 
Required
e.g for text, type and checbox 
<input type="text" name="Inputs[]['customInputName']" >



$inputs  = json_decode($request->input('Inputs'), 1);
```

By default, it should the arrays should be pre sort if you have checked Require on first form, if not then sort it with Laravel collect or some PHP function

```
$inputs = usort($inputs, function ($a, $b){    
  return ($a['checkedValues'] == 'Required' && $a['checkedValues'] == 
  'Alphabets Only')
});
```

Run loop and store, Hope you get the idea.